# Calling a function from a user entered variable [no eval()]

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button 'thing' that handles buttons.
I need to have a way to call a user defined function when the button is clicked.
Here is an examples of an element that would be selected as a button:

`<section class = 'button' buttonaction = 'aFunction()'></section>`

So, when the button is clicked I want it to get the `aFunction()` value and use it to call that function.

Example:

```
elem.onclick = function(){
    action = this.getAttribute('buttonaction');
    action();
}
```

I know this example is wrong, but I think it conveys what I want to do.
Thanks,
- Michael Mitchell

Comment: where and how is aFunction() defined?

Comment: Do you realise that calling random functions in the global scope is probably a bad idea?

Comment: @Patrick it would be defined some where on the page with in `<script>` tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup your functions something like this:

```
var my_allowed_functions = {
    func1: function(arg1, arg) {
        alert(arg1 + arg2);
    },
    func2: function(arg1, arg) {
        alert(arg1 + arg2);
    }
};
```

And just call one of them by name:

```
my_allowed_functions['func1'].apply(this, argument_array);
```

Comment: or just `my_allowed_functions['func1']()`

Comment: Is there any difference, or is it just shorter?

Comment: @MichaelMitchell if you don't care about the arguments (you don't), there is no need to call the function via `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<section class = 'button' buttonaction='aFunction'></section>
```

script :

```
var aFunction = function(){};

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

[].forEach.call(buttons,function(button){
 button.onclick = function(event){
  var ct = event.currentTarget;
  var func = ct.getAttribute("buttonaction");
  window[func]()

 }
}
```

however , when you do  `window[func]()` you are still doing a scoped eval.

so why not just do :

```
<section class='button' onclick='aFunction()'></section>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to run arbitrary code without running arbitrary code. Your concern with `eval` is the security risk, however, if you used a different function named `ponies` to somehow run user entered code instead it would still be as dangerous.

Your requirements demand `eval`, so that is what you should use, or rethink your requirements.

Comment: Note that the requirement is not to run arbitrary code but rather call an arbitrary function from a predefined set.

Comment: @JanDvorak The question says "user defined function". I am assuming this means the function to be invoked is defined by the user, and as such is arbitrary.

Comment: Actually, this is not the case. Read the question comments.

Comment: @JanDvorak `it would be defined some where on the page with in <script> tags` I didn't see that comment. That changes the question quite a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another method, with `window`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
//Create the function
var fn = function(){
  alert('ok');
};

//Call the function
var str = 'fn';
window[str]();
//-->
</script>
```